# Mysql multiple joins with same columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey not sure I am doing this right but trying to get all the groups a user is part of ranging from host to request to join, along with the media and request count for the ones he manages.

First off I have the following code and would be nice to include the Select request count in the separate function some how in it?

Second and more importantly, the return data is incorrect.

Here is my code and tech stack (Mysql, nodejs)

Multiple Group Joins:

```js
var qSelect = "SELECT g.id, g.title, g_h.member_type, g_a.member_type, g_mod.member_type, g_m.member_type, g_invite.member_type, g_req.member_type, m.media_link" +
                    " FROM Groups g" +
                    " LEFT JOIN Group_Hosts g_h ON (g_h.user_id = ? AND g_h.group_id = g.id)" +
                    " LEFT JOIN Group_Admins g_a ON (g_a.user_id = ? AND g_a.group_id = g.id)" +
                    " LEFT JOIN Group_Moderators g_mod ON (g_mod.user_id = ? AND g_mod.group_id = g.id)" +
                    " LEFT JOIN Group_Members g_m ON (g_m.user_id = ? AND g_m.group_id = g.id AND g_m.group_id IS NULL)" +
                    " LEFT JOIN Group_Invites g_invite ON (g_invite.user_id = ? AND g_invite.group_id = g.id)" +
                    " LEFT JOIN Group_Requests g_req ON (g_req.user_id = ? AND g_req.group_id = g.id)" +
                    " LEFT JOIN Media m ON g.id = m.group_id" +
                    " ORDER BY g.id ASC";
                var qValues = [user_id, user_id, user_id, user_id, user_id, user_id];
                var qCall = mysql.format(qSelect, qValues);
                mysql_pool.getConnection(function(err_pool, connection) {
                    if (err_pool) {
                        connection.release();
                        console.log(' Error getting mysql_pool connection: ' + err_pool);
                        throw err_pool;
                    }
                    connection.query(qCall, function(err, groupsFound, fields) {
                        connection.release();
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("get groupsFound error: " + err);
                            res.json({
                                http_code: 500,
                                error_message: 'Server Error: Please Try Again.'
                            });
                        } else {
                            console.log("groups hosted", groupsFound);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
```

Code for Request Count

```
async.eachSeries(groupArrManaged, function(i, callback_loop) {
                        var qSelect = "SELECT COUNT (*) AS requests FROM Group_Requests WHERE group_id = ?";
                        var qValues = [i.id];
                        var qCall = mysql.format(qSelect, qValues);
                        mysql_pool.getConnection(function(err_pool, connection) {
                            if (err_pool) {
                                console.log(' Error getting mysql_pool connection: ' + err_pool);
                                connection.release();
                                throw err_pool;
                            }
                            connection.query(qCall, function(err, requestCount, fields) {
                                connection.release();
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log("get count of group requests error: " + err);
                                    res.json({
                                        http_code: 500,
                                        error_message: 'Server Error: Please Try Again.'
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    i['notification'] = requestCount[0].requests;
                                    groupArr.push(i);

                                }
                                callback_loop(null);
                            });
                        });
                    },
                    function(err) {
                        // if any of the file processing produced an error, err would equal that error
                        if (err) {
                            // One of the iterations produced an error.
                            console.log('A group request count failed to process:', err);
                            res.json({
                                http_code: 500,
                                error_message: 'Server Error: Please Try Again.'
                            });
                        } else {
                            res.json(groupArr);
                        }
                    });
```

Here is the CORRECT Results (I pulled this prior to bringing all the individual queries into one)

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Bridged",
        "member_type": 3,
        "media_link": null
    },
    {
        "id": 38,
        "title": "Group test 1 notif",
        "member_type": 1,
        "media_link": null
    },
    {
        "id": 30,
        "title": "BR group test 1 hst",
        "member_type": 6,
        "media_link": null,
        "notification": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 31,
        "title": "BR group test 1 md",
        "member_type": 6,
        "media_link": null,
        "notification": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 35,
        "title": "Test 03",
        "member_type": 6,
        "media_link": "g_b365be55936e899cec5f39fdf137c805b61718e8.png",
        "notification": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 48,
        "title": "Dynamic link",
        "member_type": 6,
        "media_link": null,
        "notification": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 34,
        "title": "Test 02",
        "member_type": 5,
        "media_link": "g_b365be55936e899cec5f39fdf137c805b61718e8.png",
        "notification": 0
    }
]
```

Here is what I am getting with the above query:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Bridged",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": null
    },
    {
        "id": 29,
        "title": "BR group test 1 edit",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": "g_c598643099af29049e07a8db425db006114648da.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 30,
        "title": "BR group test 1 hst",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": null
    },
    {
        "id": 31,
        "title": "BR group test 1 md",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": null
    },
    {
        "id": 32,
        "title": "Group name here 1",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": null
    },
    {
        "id": 33,
        "title": "Test 01",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": "g_52792468d7811a5feddb5514d1a99e7362c90f4f.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 34,
        "title": "Test 02",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": "g_b365be55936e899cec5f39fdf137c805b61718e8.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 35,
        "title": "Test 03",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": "g_b365be55936e899cec5f39fdf137c805b61718e8.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 37,
        "title": "Group test 1",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": null
    },
    {
        "id": 38,
        "title": "Group test 1 notif",
        "member_type": 1,
        "media_link": null
    },
    {
        "id": 39,
        "title": "This is test 1",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": "g_b365be55936e899cec5f39fdf137c805b61718e8.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 40,
        "title": "Chery baby",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": "g_cdf5168c87f3ccfeac4cccf5ae9224898f63f27e.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 41,
        "title": "Bigger better",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": "g_a6479d55c61019770eab71da12280ba4af7e9f83.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 42,
        "title": "Test05",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": null
    },
    {
        "id": 43,
        "title": "Location test",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": null
    },
    {
        "id": 44,
        "title": "Just another Test",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": null
    },
    {
        "id": 46,
        "title": "OnlyFit Folks",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": null
    },
    {
        "id": 47,
        "title": "MS2",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": null
    },
    {
        "id": 48,
        "title": "Dynamic link",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": null
    },
    {
        "id": 49,
        "title": "Dynamic",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": null
    },
    {
        "id": 50,
        "title": "Qwqq",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": null
    },
    {
        "id": 51,
        "title": "Test Group",
        "member_type": null,
        "media_link": null
    }
]
```

One thing to note, I do not want duplicates if a user is a group member and a host, admin or moderator (because they can be both)

Appreciate any help

Comment: Pls use the following guidance to improve your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query Not really sure why node.js is relevant to this question if you just would like to have a single query that returns certain results. What programming language you call the query from is not relevant if your question is just about the query, not about how other parts of the code interacts with the query.

Comment: It is relevant because I am using async lib and have written code in javascript, so people are not confused by the surrounding syntax, and I am following the guidance there. As oppose to just tacking a link on, please provide suggestion or feedback and not just something anyone can add...

Comment: How did you obtain corrected results? Please show the *individual queries*. Also, what is the relationship of these *group* tables? One-to-one? One-to-many? Also, database design could be normalized a bit here where you do not maintain '_' suffixed tables but keep **one** group table with indicator field for *host*, *admin*, *moderator*...

Comment: The answer below worked well for me, thanks for your feedback though

Comment: @Lion789 the fact that you use node.js is not rekevant here, since your question is about the queries, not your js code. Including the js dode is just a distraction in this case.

Comment: Removed the tag, besides that nothing else was pushing towards it.

Answer (score 1):

Joins are not appropriate here. The only tables you're actually joining are Groups, Group_XXX, and Media. Join these tables and then union the results like:

```
(select g.id,g.title,gh.membertype,m.media_link from groups g join Group_Hosts  gh on (g.id=gh.group_id and gh.user_id=?) left join Media m on (g.id=m.group_id))
union
(select g.id,g.title,ga.membertype,m.media_link from groups g join Group_Admins ga on (g.id.ga.group_id and ga.user_id=?) left join Media m on (g.id=m.group_id))
union...
```

You could get hacky and try to include the request count in this same set by using a final union like:

```
union
SELECT "filler","filler",COUNT (*),"filler" FROM Group_Requests WHERE group_id = ?
```

But I don't see anything wrong with using 2 queries for retrieving 2 fundamentally different pieces of data.

Comment: Thanks for the response, only thing for the request count is that it depends on 3 of the different group types, is there a way to pull those out or join the request count for only those three via select count, maybe as a sub query?

Comment: Yes, sub queries would work there, something like `select (select count(*) from table1)+(select count(*) from table2)` would return the total numbers of rows in both tables.

Comment: Thank you! This worked well, one last thing, if I do the union, is there a way to call distinct so on one of the unioned queries only groups that do not exist in the previous three unions are returned?